# How to start mongodb-community as current user instead of root?

Tags: mongodb

I have installed mongodb-community according to:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

For some reason the permissions for running the service is set to "root" instead of my current user. Which result in that I can't start the service.

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents 
❯ brew services ls                            
Name              Status      User          File
mongodb-community error  3584 root          ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
```

What permissions do I need to change?

I've verified that the permissions of these files are set to my current user:

```
/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
/usr/local/var/log/mongodb
/usr/local/var/mongodb
```

I've also tried to load and unload this plist file with the launchagent:

```
homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
```

The permission of the plist file (that brew services list refers to) seems to be set to my current user:

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents 
❯ ls -la homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 <myusername>  staff  971 Aug 23 08:57 homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution:

```
> ls -l /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
srwx------  1 root  wheel  0 Aug 22 14:41 /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
> sudo rm -rf /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
> brew services restart mongodb-community
> brew services list
Name              Status  User          File
mongodb-community started <username> ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
```